# most efficient way of using split with strip in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a history file, which has daily data, since 2004. I have one function, which called on daily basis, this function look for the lines which has respective date in date column, and do the operation for that date.

So for every line, i'm using `strip` to remove `\n` or `\r\n`, and then splitting it by `comma` to get the data of that particular date.

I want to do in memory and time efficient way.

My code line looks like `line.strip().split(',')`. The issue with this code line, is it's taking a lot of time, `~740 seconds` for `292044182`. I have checked it using `cProfile`.

I'm just looking for more efficient ways do this. I searched for `re` module of python, but found it is taking more time than my previous one.

Comment: If you gave some context of what you are trying to do, we could suggest alternative ways of achieving it. For example if you are reading a CSV file, you might just use the `csv` module or `pandas`. Again, this is important information because as the question is right now we can't offer anything better than `strip().split()`

Comment: I recommend using command line tools like sed

Comment: @Tomerikoo, added more details in the questions,

Comment: What do you mean *respective date*? The current day? If so, why go over a file of 16 years just to get the latest entries. It sounds like the setting is more rather than the use of `strip` and `split`

Comment: @Tomerikoo, i need to iterate over every date since 2004, and every day i need to perform some operation.